# Adding blank spaces into a string in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I have this code

```
String coNum = customerOrderLine.coNum.PadLeft(10 - customerOrderLine.coNum.Length);
```

I know that `customerOrderLine.coNum = "123456"`  So I should end up with coNum being having 4 empty spaces at the front of it but I end up with it being "123456".  How do I fix this?  I tried `PadRight` in case that was the mistake and it also failed to work.  I have to have the 4 empty spaces at the beginning to pass it into the API I am working on or it will fail.

Comment: Looks like it should work. Are you sure it's not padded? Display the string to make sure, and put delimiters around: "[" + coNum + "]";

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[PadLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk6ydzx.aspx) takes a total length as a parameter, so I think you want

```
String coNum = customerOrderLine.coNum.PadLeft(10);
```

Comment: Wow you are right.  I totally didn't read the msdn page closely enough.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have incorrectly specified the `totalWidth` parameter of the Pad* method.
From docs:

> The number of characters in the resulting string, equal to the number
>   of original characters plus any additional padding characters.[...] If totalWidth is equal to the length of this instance, the method
>   returns a new string that is identical to this instance.

Answer (score 0):

[PadLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07.aspx) does not specify a default character to pad with; your second argument should be the character to use for the pad, i.e.:

```
String coNum = customerOrderLine.coNum.PadLeft(10, ' ');
```

Edit: Also the first argument should be total desired length, not number of pad characters to add, per @Matthew's answer.